# How to sum prices from 1 hour before to 1 hour after each row's time, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe such as below:

```
  id price hour minute  date
  1  10    03   07      01/11
  2  4     03   59      01/11
  3  5     02   21      01/11
  4  6     03   47      02/09
  5  1     04   28      02/04
  6  7    05   50      01/11
  7  3     02   01      01/11
  8  2     01   23      01/11
  ...
```

and i want an output like:

```
  id price hour minute  date   cumprice
  1  10    03   07      01/11  19
  2  4     03   59      01/11  14
  3  5     02   21      01/11  20
  4  6     03   47      02/09  6
  5  1     04   28      02/04  1
  6  7     05   50      01/11  7
  7  3     02   01      01/11  10
  8  2     01   23      01/11  10
  ...
```

I dont have any idea to do this job fast.
anybody could help me, to do this fast ?

Answer (score 3):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `date` and use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to add a column with the `sum` of the prices per group:

```
df['cumsprice'] = df.groupby('date').price.transform('sum')

   id  price  hour  minute   date  cumsprice
0   1     10     3       7  01/11         19
1   2      4     3      59  01/11         19
2   3      5     2      21  01/11         19
3   4      6     3      47  02/09          6
4   5      1     4      28  02/04          1
```

---

**Update**

Update after changing the expected solution. In order to group by consecutive dates that are equal, you can create a custom grouper for by checking on which rows the dates change, and taking the `cumsum` of these:

```
g = df.date.ne(df.date.shift(1))
df['cumprice'] = df.groupby(g.cumsum()).price.transform('sum')    

print(df)
   id  price  hour  minute   date  cumsprice  cumprice
0   1     10     3       7  01/11         31      19.0
1   2      4     3      59  01/11         31      19.0
2   3      5     2      21  01/11         31      19.0
3   4      6     3      47  02/09          6       6.0
4   5      1     4      28  02/04          1       1.0
5   6     12     5      50  01/11         31      12.0
```

Comment: Dear @yatu thank you for your answer, but this code isn't match the updated dataframe,

Comment: Well this slight change in the expected solution will completely change the way to solve the problem, as the solution isn't a pandas groupby @getdata

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask a new question, and you'll surely get it answered :-)

Comment: Updated the solution @getdata

Comment: Thank you so much @yatu, but i want  prices from 1 hour before to 1 hour after each row's time (hour and minute)

Comment: for example, one row's time is 01:10 so the window is from 12:10 to 02:10,